# Using SUM CASE with IN with SQL

Tags: php, sql, t-sql

I am building a site which has articles which are targeted by subscription,  and those articles also have categories.I have the following query SQL query to get the categories and the total number of articles belonging to that category, this creates an archive list if you will. 
But as the users also have subscriptions,  I want to make the archive only list the articles and counts where the users has subscribed too.

```
SELECT category.id, 
       category.category, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN category.id = article.category 
                      THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
            END) AS Number 
  FROM dbo.category 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.article 
            ON article.category=category.id 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.articleProfile 
            ON article.id = articleProfile.articleId 
 WHERE category.id != '33'  
GROUP BY 
       category.id, 
       category.category 
ORDER BY 
       category ASC
```

This on its work works fine. It brings the correct amount of all articles, but if I try using an IN to include the subscriptions in the query, like so

```
SELECT category.id, 
       category.category, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN category.id = article.category 
                     THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
           END) AS Number 
  FROM dbo.category 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.article 
            ON article.category=category.id 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.articleProfile 
            ON article.id = articleProfile.articleId 
 WHERE category.id != '33' 
       AND articleProfile.profileId IN ('1000000382','1000000388') 
GROUP BY 
       category.id, 
       category.category 
ORDER BY 
       category ASC
```

So my desired output will be

```
Category 1           5 
Category 2           22
Category 3           56
```

and so on.
However, it is counting the article more than once  for each subscription and giving too large a count for each category. 
Is it possible to use distinct here at all? Or is there simply a more efficient method of writing this query?

Comment: why do you need outer join? is it not a case of just inner join and count instead of sum?

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy in this case, but he probably _has_ one - a condition in the `WHERE` clause that references a `LEFT JOIN`ed table turns it into an `INNER JOIN` (because `null` values fail the condition).  You probably want to pre-aggregate the articles anyways (subquery table reference), which would make the `ORDER BY` narrower.  Can we get some sample starting data (and table creation scripts) to go with the target destination data, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: You are outer joining the tables article and articleProfile, but then you ask explicitely for profiles with certain ids. So there is nothing outer joined anymore. Your outer joins become inner joins, only more complicated. Move your criteria from the WHERE clause to the ON clause, if you want outer joins. However, in your example you don't want outer joins.

So, back to your problem. You want to count the selected articles. Use COUNT for this. Either with DISTINCT:

```
SELECT 
  category.id, 
  category.category, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT article.id)
FROM dbo.category 
INNER JOIN dbo.article ON article.category=category.id 
INNER JOIN dbo.articleProfile ON article.id = articleProfile.articleId 
WHERE category.id != '33' 
  AND articleProfile.profileId IN ('1000000382','1000000388') 
GROUP BY category.id, category.category 
ORDER BY category ASC;
```

Or by not joining the profiles, which is what I would prefer. But that is just a matter of personal preference, I guess.

```
SELECT 
  category.id, 
  category.category, 
  COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.category 
INNER JOIN dbo.article ON article.category=category.id 
WHERE category.id != '33' 
AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM dbo.articleProfile 
  WHERE articleProfile.articleId = article.id 
  AND articleProfile.profileId IN ('1000000382','1000000388') 
)
GROUP BY category.id, category.category 
ORDER BY category ASC;
```

Comment: Thankyou for your quick response.I clearly need to revisit my joins and sql in general. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT category.id, 
       category.category, 
       COUNT(*) AS Number 
  FROM dbo.category 
       JOIN dbo.article 
            ON article.category=category.id 
       JOIN dbo.articleProfile 
            ON article.id = articleProfile.articleId 
 WHERE category.id != '33' 
       AND articleProfile.profileId IN ('1000000382','1000000388') 
GROUP BY 
       category.id, 
       category.category 
ORDER BY 
       category ASC
```